# Clear Understanding With ReturnUrl

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, returnurl

I have three links in my menu

**1.Login**

**2.Create Account**

**3.Default Page**

Few hours it worked fine (fine in the sense when I click create new account it takes me to the same page and If I click login it takes me to the login page). But now when I click the create account and the immediately click Login link it is showing me with return URL as shown below:

**`http://localhost:16491/Website1/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWebsite1%2fCreateUser.aspx`**

Why this is happening?Can anyone say me the reason or what I need to change so that it should point the same URL

As from all over the internet they are saying that I need to check If the user is authenticated and redirected to specific page instead of **`DestinationPageURL`**

This is what I have done and it's redirecting to the default page as expceted.But I want to know why the Returnurl has appended and how to remove it.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
      loggeddetails.Text = "Welcome"
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, True)
      Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
  Else
      loggeddetails.Text = "Welcome Guest,"
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent hours of understanding this and finally got working with this solution as I have made **`login control`** forced to redirect to the **`destination page Url`** as shown below:

```
Protected Sub Login1_LoggedIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Login1.LoggedIn
    Response.Redirect(Login1.DestinationPageUrl)
End Sub
```